# keyboard shortcuts and MacVim 7.4

Tags: macvim

I've used [fuzzyfinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) to change between buffers for a long time (since 2008-2009). I've upgraded MacVim no less than 10 times since I've started using fuzzy finder. I've had this in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <Leader>t :FufBuffer<CR>
nnoremap <D-t> :FufBuffer<CR>
```

A few months back I upgraded to 7.4 (73). And now Command-T just opens a tab. I want to de-activate this behavior and have Command-T just make FufBuffer show up.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `:help cmd-key` and `:help macmenu`.  As you noticed <kbd>⌘-T</kbd> is now mapped to "New Tab" in the menu.  You need to free up <kbd>⌘-T</kbd> before you can remap it to something else.

Something like the following should be added to your **.gvimrc** (.vimrc will not work):

```
" Free Up Cmd-t
macmenu File.New\ Tab key=<nop>

" Remap it to fuzzyFinder
nmap <D-t> :FufBuffer<CR>
```